FAST API withholding async requests from psycopg2 PostgresSQL Database layer
We have FAST API application which is fetching data from PostgresSQL Database. The issue with the endpoint is it is withholding multiple requests, waiting for 2-3 requests to complete before sending back the responses to the calling client. Following is the main.py code which has the REST API endpoint:
import os
import time
import traceback
from typing import Optional
from datetime import datetime
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI(docs_url="/tc/docs",
              redoc_url="/tc/redoc",
              openapi_url="/tc/openapi.json", )

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    expose_headers=["*"]
)

@app.get('/tc/trackLoc')
async def get_people_location_all(fromDate: str, start_time: str, district: Optional[str] = None,
                               end_time: Optional[str] = None,
                               limit: Optional[int] = 100, offset: Optional[int] = 0,
                               ):
    
    if True:
        try:
            pg_r = Readers.pg_reader()
            start_datetime = fromDate + "T" + start_time + ".000000Z"
            logger.info("start_data time is: " + start_datetime)
            now = datetime.now()
            curr_date = str(now.date())
            if end_time is not None:
                end_datetime = fromDate + "T" + end_time + ".000000Z"
            else:
                end_datetime = curr_date + "T23:59:59.000000Z"
            t1 = time.time()
            res = await pg_r.retrieve_item_by_date(db, fromDate, limit, offset, None, None, None, None,
                                                   start_datetime, end_datetime)
            print("time taken to complete the request from fastapi = ", str(time.time() - t1), " seconds")
            logger.info("Track Locations output --> \n" + str(res))
            return res
        except:
            content = "\n ERROR === \n"
            content = content + str(traceback.format_exc()) + "\n\n"
            logger.error("Error while running Track Locations endpoint -->")
            logger.error(str(content))
            return content
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Unauthorized Access")

Following is the code which fetches data from database:
def retrieve_item_by_date(self, limit, offset, unitid, punitid, prouteid, filters,
                                       start_time, end_time):
        try:
            self.logger.info("Pg_client retrieve method called by date ")
            self.logger.info("extracting for date == " + str(start_time))
            self.logger.info("dslunit id got ==  " + str(unitid))
            slsunitid_tablename = "route_and_pgtroute_slsid_view" if unitid or punitid else None
            unit_id = unitid or punitid
            pgt_route_tablename = "routeid_prouteid_view" if prouteid else None
            actual_filters = self.apply_filters_actuals(filters)
            self.logger.info("actual filters got ==  " + str(filters))
            params_tuple = (start_time, end_time, slsunitid_tablename, unit_id, proute_tablename, prouteid,
                            actual_filters[3], actual_filters[1], actual_filters[0], actual_filters[2], limit, offset)
            query = "SELECT * FROM get_data(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) " \
                    "limit %s offset %s"
            manager = PostgresConnect()
            conn = manager.get_connection()
            if conn:
                try:
                    cur = conn.cursor()
                    print("Cursor created == ", cur)
                    cur.execute(query, params_tuple)
                    results = cur.fetchall()
                    column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
                    result_list = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=column_names).fillna(0.0).to_dict(orient='records')
                    conn.commit()
                    return result_list
                except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
                    print("Error while executing query:", error)
                    conn.rollback()
                finally:
                    if cur:
                        cur.close()
                    manager.put_connection(conn)
            else:
                print("Error While creating the connection")
                return None
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()

When applied a load of 10 users over 5 minutes it is holding back 2-3 responses together and responding to the user. Following is the pod log:
*********************Fetched Keyvault Object *********************
****************************Fetched Secret value**********************
*********************Fetched Keyvault Object *********************
****************************Fetched Secret value**********************
time taken to get from postgres ==  1.6969659328460693  seconds
time taken to get from postgres ==  1.389324426651001  seconds
time taken to get from postgres ==  1.7121288776397705  seconds
time taken to run the complete query =  1.7162621021270752  secs
INFO:     127.0.0.6:44539 - "POST /tc/graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
time taken to run the complete query =  1.4071722030639648  secs
time taken to run the complete query =  1.7274298667907715  secs
INFO:     127.0.0.6:42929 - "POST /tc/graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.6:37509 - "POST /tc/graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
/code/app/pg_client.py:326: FutureWarning: Downcasting object dtype arrays on .fillna, .ffill, .bfill is deprecated and will change in a future version. Call result.infer_objects(copy=False) instead. To opt-in to the future behavior, set `pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)`
  result_list = pd.DataFrame(route_result, columns=column_names).fillna(0.0).to_dict(orient='records')
/code/app/pg_client.py:326: FutureWarning: Downcasting object dtype arrays on .fillna, .ffill, .bfill is deprecated and will change in a future version. Call result.infer_objects(copy=False) instead. To opt-in to the future behavior, set `pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)`
  result_list = pd.DataFrame(route_result, columns=column_names).fillna(0.0).to_dict(orient='records')
*********************Fetched Keyvault Object *********************
****************************Fetched Secret value**********************
*********************Fetched Keyvault Object *********************
****************************Fetched Secret value**********************
time taken to get from postgres ==  1.1929430961608887  seconds
time taken to get from postgres ==  1.5283558368682861  seconds
time taken to run the complete query =  1.203705072402954  secs
INFO:     127.0.0.6:58199 - "POST /tc/graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
time taken to run the complete query =  1.5393061637878418  secs
INFO:     127.0.0.6:38951 - "POST /tc/graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

If you look at the above logs, one request's average time is 3 seconds because 2 requests are getting resolved together. What can be done to make sure that each request gets resolved individually and is returned to the user?

Please see this question. Basically, you've marked your functions as async def, but you're not running any asynchronous operations, so FastAPI will run them sequentially. Changing to just def should make them run in parallel.
